# jquery fancybox media helper not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Here you can see my source code

http://xoda.paperplane.io/

I am trying to make it, so when you click on the youtube link it should open the youtube video with fancybox,  as can be seen here.

http://jsfiddle.net/hR5Wk/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

I just dont get why mine isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your page, jQuery load multiple times... please remove one:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

it will fix your problem

Comment: DUDE YOU'RE EPIC!! This solved my problem !! thanks so much